# angular 6 post method issue

Tags: angular, angular6

I am trying to pass component to service file. I have an issue in my service file.
The error said 'can not find name array'. please check attachment.

```
  updateInvoiceHeaderStatus(fileNameFormArray:Array<any> ,orgName: string,fromDate: string,toDate: string){
 return this.http.post(`${this.selectedfilenameurl}/${orgName}/${fromDate}/${toDate}`,fileNameFormArray)
```

}

[image]

Comment: Please show how you are calling the service from your component

Comment: this is worked in angular 6.

Answer (score 1):

From angular 7 typescript 3.1 is introduced in core framework so you just need to check tslint.json[image: array-type in the rules of tslint.json]

Answer (score 0):

Are you using TSLint or Code Prettier extensions? because those are marking Array as an error due to not having a space bar after the ':' mark , anyways your code should run without a problem.

```
updateInvoiceHeaderStatus(fileNameFormArray: Array<any> ,orgName: string,fromDate: string,toDate: string){
 return this.http.post(`${this.selectedfilenameurl}/${orgName}/${fromDate}/${toDate}`,fileNameFormArray)
```

Comment: this service class works with below configurations 
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.1.10",
    "@angular/cdk": "^7.0.1",
    "@angular/common": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/http": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/material": "^7.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "^6.1.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.3",

  }

Comment: not working with 
"@angular/animations": "7.0.2",
    "@angular/cdk": "^7.0.1",
    "@angular/common": "7.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "7.0.2",
    "@angular/core": "7.0.2",
    "@angular/forms": "7.0.2",
    "@angular/http": "7.0.2",
    "@angular/material": "^7.0.1",

Answer (score 0):

This is a style issue, not a compilation issue. It works fine, but your style configuration just doesn't accept it.

Try using `any[]` in place of `Array<any>`